# Can't make a XMLHttpRequest inside a Google Action Webhook

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, webhooks, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to teach myself Google Actions, so far so good. My last step to successfully build my project is to use Webhooks to retrieve data from a server.

To do so, I use `XMLHttpRequest` to send a request to my server, retrieve a JSON data, parse it and make Google Assistant say it out loud.

Here is the code:

```js
const {conversation} = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const app = conversation({debug: true});

app.handle('start_scene_initial_prompt', (conv) => {
  var json = {};
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = 'https://myserver.com/getInfo?token=myauthtoken&data=tempRDC';
  xhr.open("GET", url, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            // we lost connection to mothership
            conv.add('Erreur: '+ xhr.status);
        } else {
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            conv.add('Temperature is ' + json[0].last + '°C');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        conv.add('Unknown error');
    }
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The code compiles fine, deploys too, but whatever I do I always end up with "Unknown error":

I also tried an async version, the result is the same :(

```js
const {conversation} = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const app = conversation({debug: true});

app.handle('start_scene_initial_prompt', (conv) => {
    var json = {};
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://nmyserver.com/getInfo?token=myauthtoken&data=tempRDC';
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    
    try {
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            // we lost connection to mothership
            conv.add('Erreur: '+ xhr.status);
        } else {
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            conv.add('temperature is ' + json[0].last + '°C');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        conv.add('Unknown error');
    }
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I, of course, tested the HTTP request, it works like a charm. I also adapted the code to create something similar but locally, it works too.

Can someone help?

Comment: Didn't you try alerting 'error' somehow to know what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll put my thoughts here. First of all, XMLHttpRequest is old and outdated. The `fetch` API is much more reliable and easy. Anyways, back to your code. I think your problem is that you are checking the `xhr.status` before the response is ready. You're also sending the request before you define a callback. Try using this code instead:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Do your logic
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send(null);
```